# Hosting a mocha js in a non node environment

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, mocha.js

I have a asp.net MVC app, and I want to start unit testing the javascript closures I use with the app. I have watched a few demo's on plural site, and played with the sample code in the github repository.

however, all the actual mocha.js examples assume I want to host with node, and that the npm system will get all of my dependencies. At this time I cannot install node.js on my laptop. the test code in the plural site courses all are horribaly orginized, and when I look at the files named "mocha.js" they actually contain the require.js code as well.

in any regards, Does anyone has a good "html" hostable template for mocha.js code, and a nice way to orginize the dependencies outside of the node npm system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mocha can run in the browser without having to worry about dependencies. The documentation has a section [about it](http://mochajs.org/#browser-support). As shown in the documentation, you need a page that loads and starts Mocha, and loads anything else you need:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mocha Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mocha.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>

  <!-- Load the libraries you need -->
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="expect.js"></script>
  <script src="mocha.js"></script>

  <!-- Tell Mocha what interface to use for the tests. You must do this
       before you read the test files. -->
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>

  <!-- Load the test files. This is where your tests would be located. -->
  <script src="test.array.js"></script>
  <script src="test.object.js"></script>
  <script src="test.xhr.js"></script>

  <!-- Run the tests. -->
  <script>
    mocha.checkLeaks();
    mocha.globals(['jQuery']);
    mocha.run();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've added some comments above to indicate what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Louis, I must be blind. thanks for the link~!